# Webkit bug rendering Image in centered absolute div

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Edit: I reported the bug [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152588)

I have encountered a bug with webkit that is causing me quite a bit of grief. Here is my situation. I have an image inside a centered absolute-positioned div. I want to be able to change the height of the parent of this div to have the image change heights, but retain it's aspect ratio and center alignment. The following works fine in Firefox, but fails in Chrome:

Enter the height into the text box and press enter. Here is what happens:
[image: chrome squishes and offsets the images]

I'm looking for a way to force webkit to redraw the layout correctly. I also want to make sure this is in the webkit bug tracker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Webkit bug</title></head>
  <style>
    #changesHeight {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #child {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="changesHeight" style="height: 200px;">
      <div id="child">
        <img style="height: 100%" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0" type="number" value="200">
    <script>
      document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = function(a) {
        document.getElementById('changesHeight').style.height = this.value + 'px';
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can't manage to achieve cross-browser is not necessarily a bug. Try with just your outer container and the image inside (not another child in-between), and allow the image to resize itself :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Webkit bug</title></head>
  <style>
    #changesHeight {
      position: relative;
      border : red solid 1px;
      width : 100%;
      height : 200px;
    }
    
    #changesHeight img {
      position : absolute;
      max-height : 100%;
      height : 100%;
      left : 50%;
      transform : translateX(-50%);
      border : blue dashed 1px;
    }
    
    .spacer {
      height: 2000px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="changesHeight" style="height: 200px;">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
    </div>
    
    <input style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0" type="number" value="200">
    <script>
      document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = function(a) {
        document.getElementById('changesHeight').style.height = this.value + 'px';
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will probably end up doing something like this, or maybe putting the image as a background in the div. I definitely thing it's a bug though. If you load the page with the style set to 100px, it's square, but if it's changed from javascript it is either squished vertically or not centered (div squished horizontally). It's really inconsistant